# The EB CLI cannot find Dockerfile or the Dockerrun.aws.json file in the application root directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image: why]

But Dockerfile is in fact on file in the application root directory???

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, the error is misleading...
I have to run
eb init -p docker application-name
in the same directory before that, such that the file .elasticbeanstalk can be generated.